# Incorrect results when comparing values of timestamp type with different precisions in CnosDB

Tags: database, types, cnosdb

To reproduce:

```sql
select * 
from user_queries 
where time <= to_timestamp_millis(1680856751413) 
limit 1;
```

I can't get correct resultset.

**Note**: time is TimestampNanosecond

Expected behavior: I expected to get the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the same problem. https://github.com/cnosdb/cnosdb/issues/1082. This is the issue i submitted. It seems that they have fixed it. Maybe we can use it in next version